# print preview based on gridcontrol mainview in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, devexpress, gridcontrol

How can I printpreview in my `GridControl` DevExpress based on mainview.
Here is my code:

```
private void PrintPreview()
{            
    // Get your currently selected grid row
    var rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;

    // Get the value for the given column - convert to the type you're expecting
    var obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "NIK");

    try
    {
        if (gridView1.RowCount <=0)

        {
            MessageBox.Show("DATA ROW KOSONG", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter();
            for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
            {                        
                //connection
                if (koneksi.koneksi.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    koneksi.koneksi.con.Close();
                }
                koneksi.koneksi.con.Open();

                tambah buka = new tambah();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = koneksi.koneksi.con;
                adp = new OracleDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM V_KARYAWAN, KARYAWAN_GAMBAR WHERE V_KARYAWAN.NIK = KARYAWAN_GAMBAR.KARYAWAN_FK AND V_KARYAWAN.NIK = '" + obj + "'", koneksi.koneksi.con);
            }
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "V_KARYAWAN, KARYAWAN_GAMBAR");
            kartu report = new kartu();
            report.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            report.ShowPreview();                                                               
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    } 
}
```

It was difficult for me how to solve this. I cannot take the value from `GridControl` mainview because mycode just know about `FocusedRowHandle` in `GridControl`.

```
// Get your currently selected grid row
 var rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;

// Get the value for the given column - convert to the type you're expecting
 var obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "NIK");
```

I was using oracle database.

Comment: Have you tried [`GridControl.ShowPrintPreview`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowPrintPreviewtopic) method or [`GridControl.ShowRibbonPrintPreview`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowRibbonPrintPreviewtopic) method?

Comment: no, i haven't to do that,..because i use xtrareport to show data from gridcontrol,..but i'll try first use GridControl.ShowPreview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GridControl.ShowPrintPreview`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowPrintPreviewtopic) method or [`GridControl.ShowRibbonPrintPreview`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowRibbonPrintPreviewtopic) method to show the printpreview of your `GridControl`.

But if you want to use your `XtraReport` then you are almost there. You just need to move your code for getting values into your cycle.
Here is example:

```
private void PrintPreview()
{
    try
    {
        if (gridView1.RowCount <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DATA ROW KOSONG", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            var table = new DataTable("V_KARYAWAN, KARYAWAN_GAMBAR");

            //Create columns in table form gridView1.
            foreach (GridColumn column in gridView1.Columns)
                table.Columns.Add(column.FieldName, column.ColumnType);

            //Export gridView1 to table.
            for (int rowHandle = 0; rowHandle < gridView1.DataRowCount; rowHandle++)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();

                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    row[column] = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column.ColumnName);

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //Show report.
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(table);

            kartu report = new kartu();
            report.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            report.ShowPreview();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried for your suggest code ,..but it just show first data in gridcontrol row but another row wasn't ,...i dont't know how to solve this,...perhaps i got the wrong code in for loop ?

Comment: @aminvincent It is hard to say what is wrong in your code, because I have no information what have you done and what is the structure of your underline datasource in your `GridControl`. Can you add this information into your question?

Comment: for example i have 4 rows data show in gridcontrol and 4 columns,..mycolumn (NIK,NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE NUMBER) and my 4 rows data are (1, VINCENT, JAKARTA, 1234), (2, FIAN, KUDUS, 567), (3, DIANA, JEPARA, 90987), (4, VIA, SEMARANG, 6778) . i wanna show that data in xtrareport based on gridcontrol devespress. but your suggest code above just show first data row in my xtrareport,....how can i solve this?

Comment: @aminvincent You can directly export your `GridView` to `DataTable` and use the result for your `XtraReport`. I have updated my answer. Take a look at the code.

Comment: after i try n erorr for my project,.. and i use your code above,..it's work,..my problem is because of my xtrareport databinding,.. thanks so much for your help....nice...